# Jquery capture click event outside of popup

Tags: jquery, bpopup

Im using bPopUp to show a hidden div that is working well. This bPopup is triggered by a DDL when an item is selected. Now, I want to reset my DDL to value 0 when the user clicked outside of popUp.

PS: Im able to close my popUp, unless I click for two times on html page I cant able to capture that click event.

```
$("html").click(function () {

    if ($('#bPopup').is(":visible")) {
        $('#ddl').val('0');
    }

});
```

Comment: I guess. where is your  $('#bPopup') click event

Comment: You can use body too.

Comment: I defined body width as 980px. So if user click event isnt that range it isnt working

Comment: Can you post your popup click also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var container = $(your container selector);
    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
    &&
    container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
                                {
                                    container.hide();
                                }
});
```

try this code

Answer (score 0):

You can use `event.target` to indentify the clicked element, see below code :

```
$("html").click(function (e) {

    // check if id of clicked element is not bPopup
    if(e.target.id!="bPopup")
    {
        $('#ddl').val('0');
     }
    if ($('#bPopup').is(":visible")) {
        $('#ddl').val('0');
    }

});
```

Comment: down voter please comment... can't we use event.target to identify the clicked element?

Comment: Im able capture outside click event. When a popUp appears, the background is appears to be dark. when the user click on the dark area then I should reset my DDL. Now, when I click on dark area I can close the popup but not able to reset the DDL. But If click one more time I can reset my ddl.

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle of your problem, so that I can help you better.